# how can i change the html rendering of d:formalpara

Tags: xslt, docbook

### This is how the default configuration renders a formalpara:

this:

```
<formalpara>
  <title>foo</title>
  <para>bar</para>
</formalpara>
```

will be rendered as this:

```
<p>
  <span class="formalpara-title">foo</span>
  bar
</p>
```

I already set `<xsl:param name="runinhead.default.title.end.punct"></xsl:param>` so the stupid point doesnt get rendered anymore.

### This is what i actually want:

```
<div class="formalpara">
  <h2 class="title">foo</h2>
  <p>bar</p>
</div>
```

### This is what i've done so far:

I changed:

```
<xsl:template match="d:formalpara">
  <xsl:call-template name="paragraph">

.....

</xsl:template>
```

to:

```
<xsl:template match="d:formalpara">
  <xsl:call-template name="block.object">

.....

</xsl:template>
```

and I changed:

```
<xsl:template match="d:formalpara/d:title|d:formalpara/d:info/d:title">

.....

  <span class="formalpara-title">

  .....

  </span>
</xsl:template>
```

to:

```
<xsl:template match="d:formalpara/d:title|d:formalpara/d:info/d:title">

.....

  <h2 class="title">

  .....

  </h2>
</xsl:template>
```

This is what will be rendered now:

```
<div class="formalpara">
  <h2 xmlns:d="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook" class="title">foo</h2>
  bar
</div>
```

## What is my actual Question?

1. Why is the `xmlns:d="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"` getting rendered?
2. How can I get the `<p>` tag around my `bar`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to avoid the namespace declaration `xmlns:d="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"` on the `h2` element by adding `exclude-result-prefixes="d"` on your `xsl:stylesheet` (respectively `xsl:transform`) element.

I would assume that adding

```
<xsl:template match="d:formalpara/d:para">
  <p>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </p>
</xsl:template>
```

ensures the transformation of the `para` element child of a `formalpara`, but I haven't checked whether that works.